# Spark: unique id across executor

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible using `Accumulator` in Spark to generate a unique ID that can be read across the executors too, in a way to generate some sort of "unique ids"? From the documentation I can understand that you can access to it only from the driver. In case, is there any alternative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible using Accumulator in Spark to generate a unique ID

It is not possible

> is there any alternative path?

- `zipWithIndex` or `zipWithUniqueId` for `RDD`.
- `withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())` for `Dataset[Row]` / `DataFrame`.

Comment: What is the best way to 'unzip' the IDs acquired with zipWithUniqueID? I'm using a join, but its making my program unstable.